# how to prevent user to update a post after 24 hours django

Tags: python, django, django-models

i want to prevent the user to update the post after 24 hours from the post date

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    title= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    post = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edit = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields = '__all__'

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,SuccessMessageMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    success_message = "updated successfully"
    template_name = 'store/create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lists')
    def form_valid(self,form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

i want to let the user only be able to update the post before 24 hours during the Post date
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the queryset such that only the posts that it only contains `Post`s that are written within the last 24 hours:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,SuccessMessageMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    success_message = "updated successfully"
    template_name = 'store/create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lists')

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            date__gte=now() - timedelta(days=1)
        )

    def form_valid(self,form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This will return a HTTP 404 response in case the update period has been "expired".

Comment: thanks alot , thats what i looked for , can we set an error message instead of 404 error ?

Comment: @art_cs: well the standard message is a translated variant of `"No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query"`. So here it will be something like `No posts found matching the query`. You can for example use the translation mechanism to specify it differently. Or you can use a `try`-`except` mechanism for example in the dispatch function to return something else. It might however be a good idea to return a status code in the 400-499 range.

Comment: and what if i had multiple forms in get_context_data() context=super().get_context_data() still work for other forms ?

Comment: @art_cs: yes, since it simply never gets to `get_context_data` if the object does not exists. Obtaining the object will raise a `Http404`, and if it is not outdated, just return the object (like it did before).